# Why a garbage address value (0x2) is getting stored in the mutex pointer in the Glibc-2.24 POSIX pthread API: __GI___pthread_mutex_lock(mutex=0x2)

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, race-condition, glibc

I am currently working on a problem where a crash is happening in one thread which is responsible for handling different types of signals. Interestingly the crash is happening in a POSIX pthread API: `__GI___pthread_mutex_lock(mutex=0x2)` where for some unknown reasons the value `0x2` bogus address is updated in the mutex variable in the `pthread_mutex_lock()` API scope. Please refer to the following GDB backtrace collected from the core file:

```
Thread 2 (LWP 26849):
#0  __nptl_deallocate_tsd () at pthread_create.c:200
#1  0xf72af5da in start_thread (arg=0x0) at pthread_create.c:346
#2  0xf698d5f2 in ?? () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/clone.S:86
   from /tools/toolchain/arm/armbe-none-linux-gnueabi_2017/usr/armeb-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib32/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 1 (LWP 26850):
#0  __libc_do_syscall () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/libc-do-syscall.S:47
#1  0xf691d2d2 in __libc_signal_restore_set (set=0xf65fe560) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nptl-signals.h:79
#2  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:55
#3  0xf691dfba in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#4  0xf691861a in __assert_fail_base (fmt=0xf69c5f80 "%s%s%s:%u: %s%sAssertion `%s' failed.\n%n", assertion=0xf72b8b1c "mutex->__data.__owner == 0",
    assertion@entry=0x2 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x2>, file=file@entry=0xf65fef50 "", line=1, line@entry=4137570440,
    function=function@entry=0xf72b8b90 <__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.10382> "__pthread_mutex_lock") at assert.c:92
#5  0xf69186ae in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x2 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x2>, file=0xf65fef50 "", line=4137570440, line@entry=81,
    function=0xf72b8b90 <__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.10382> "__pthread_mutex_lock") at assert.c:101
#6  0xf72b15d6 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x2) at pthread_mutex_lock.c:81
#7  0xf6a29820 in handle_process_exit () at signal_handler.c:258
#8  0xf6a29ba0 in signal_handler (param=0) at signal_handler.c:331
#9  0xf6a25e98 in task_init (param=0x2efe24) at task/tasks.c:403
#10 0xf72af5ce in start_thread (arg=0x1) at pthread_create.c:335
#11 0xf698d5f2 in ?? () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/clone.S:86
   from /tools/toolchain/arm/armbe-none-linux-gnueabi_2017/usr/armeb-buildroot-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib32/libc.so.6
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) f 7
#7  0xf6a29820 in handle_process_exit () at sig/silpi_signal_handler.c:258
258     sig/signal_handler.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) p @tmr_exit_mutex
Unknown address space specifier: "tmr_exit_mutex"
(gdb) p &tmr_exit_mutex
$1 = (pthread_mutex_t *) 0xf6a43fb8 <tmr_exit_mutex>
(gdb) f 6
#6  0xf72b15d6 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x2) at pthread_mutex_lock.c:81
81      pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) p mutex
$2 = (pthread_mutex_t *) 0x2
(gdb) p &tmr_exit_mutex
$3 = (pthread_mutex_t *) 0xf6a43fb8 <tmr_exit_mutex>
(gdb) ptype tmr_exit_mutex
type = union {
    struct __pthread_mutex_s __data;
    char __size[24];
    long __align;
}
(gdb) p tmr_exit_mutex
$4 = {__data = {__lock = 0, __count = 0, __owner = 0, __kind = 0, __nusers = 0, {__spins = 0, __list = {__next = 0x0}}},
  __size = '\000' <repeats 23 times>, __align = 0}
(gdb)
```

In the `handle_process_exit()` function we are calling `pthread_mutex_lock(mutex = &tmr_exit_mutex)` pthread POSIX API and you can observe the address of the `tmr_exit_mutex (0xf6a43fb8)` variable is the same in frames 6 and 7 (means it is not corrupted) but for some unknown reasons, the address passed to the mutex parameter gets corrupted and a bogus address `0x02` gets passed as an argument to this `__GI___pthread_mutex_lock(mutex=0x2)` pthread POSIX API.

When I looked at the source-code of `pthread_mutex_lock.c` file in the glibc-2.24 source-tree available at: https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.24/source/nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c. I observed the corruption is happening at line number 81 only because if the corruption had happened earlier then the `assert (sizeof(mutex->__size) >= sizeof(mutex->__data));` at line number: 65 would have failed, so I am not able to make any rationale behind what could have happened.

Could anyone provide me the details of why this scenario would be happening and how to debug these issues using GDB or any external open-source tools if possible ?

Moreover, the race condition which has led to the undefined behavior has happened because the mutex must have been destroyed due to some other thread but it is harder to reproduce the same scenario, so can you provide me insights about what are different types of logs I should collect whenever this issue happens again because I am in a process of creating a debug image to capture all the information I can collect whenever this issue encounters again ?

In summary,
I wanted to know/debug what could be the reasons for the address which is being passed to the `mutex` parameter of the `pthread_mutex_lock(mutex=0x2)` glibc-2.24 pthread APIs ?

Comment: You said `I did try to link against libasan* and libubsan* runtime libraries while building the program`, but you actually meant you rebuilt everything with `-fsanitize=address` or `-fsanitize=undefined`, right?

Comment: Ummm, probably because your code is passing a bogus address in the first place at `sig/silpi_signal_handler.c:258`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle No, the address which is getting passed is correct I did try to print the address of the mutex variable in the GDB in frame 7, then it coming correct:
```(gdb) p &tmr_exit_mutex
$1 = (pthread_mutex_t *) 0xf6a43fb8 <tmr_exit_mutex>```

Comment: @ssbssa I did rebuild everything with `-fsanitize=address,undefined` compiler option and did link the binaries against the `libasan*` and `libubsan*` runtime libraries but I am getting the following error when executing the binary on an ARM machine:
```==790==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: ../../../../libsanitizer/asan/asan_rtl.cc:441 "((!asan_init_is_running && "ASan init calls itself!")) != (0)" (0x0, 0x0)
    <empty stack>
```

I did set the environment variable `ASAN_OPTIONS` and `UBSAN_OPTIONS` also, then also I am getting `CHECK failed` related errors.

Comment: Looks a lot like [this libasan bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27310), but that bug should have been fixed many years ago.

Comment: @ssbssa I have updated the problem statement further to pinpoint exactly where the corruption is happening.

Comment: @strikersps The design is fundamentally broken and invokes undefined behavior by calling `pthread_mutex_lock()` from a signal handler.  `pthread_mutex_lock()` is not an async-signal-safe function and it can not be safely called from within a signal handler.  That may or may not be related to your apparent memory corruption issue.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for the insights. If possible could you please elaborate upon why `pthread_mutex_lock()` is not async-signal-safe with examples and does there exist an alternative to `pthread_mutex_lock()` API in the glibc-2.24 ?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Could you please provide your insights on how can I make the `handle_process_exit()` method async-signal-safe ?

Comment: Why are you initializing the condition variable and the mutex?  If other threads are using them, you're blowing them up right out from under them.  And if other threads aren't using them, why are you calling `pthread_cond_timedwait()`?  And you can't make any of those calls from within a signal handler anyway.  See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04  Pay particular attention to the list of functions that you can safely call. `printf()` is not on that list.  Note, though, the Linux `fork()` is broken and not async signal safe.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for all the information, I get to learn a lot of things here through the discussion.
Basically what I am trying to understand here: What can be the reasons for the stack frame allocated to the glibc-2.24 API `pthread_mutex_lock(mutex = 0x2)` in the backtrace to get corrupted because this issue is happening rarely and if it is a undefined behavior then the address would be gibberish but whenever it happens we always see `0x2` bad address getting passed to the `mutex` parameter in our system.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Henle correctly states, using `pthread_*` functions from a signal handler is undefined behavior -- you have to use async-signal-safe constructs, such as atomic variables instead.

> I observed the corruption is happening at line number 81 only because if the corruption had happened earlier then the  `assert (sizeof(mutex->__size) >= sizeof(mutex->__data));` at line number: 65 would have failed,

You are mistaken: that `assert` would work just fine *regardless* of the value of `mutex` -- it doesn't evaluate the `mutex` at all, it only asserts the relationship between *sizes* of the different types involved.

> In the handle_process_exit() function we are calling `pthread_mutex_lock(mutex = &tmr_exit_mutex)`

We don't know what `mutex` is in that context. If it's a local variable (which doesn't have its address taken), that should be ok, but if it's a global, then you probably have a data race.

Without http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you further.

But using sanitizers is *unlikely* to help here, because the `libpthread` or `libc` itself is not instrumented.

Comment: The `tmr_exit_mutex` is a global mutex variable

Comment: I have added more information in the question regarding another suspicious thread which is also running at the time of the crash.

Comment: You are right about the following:
You are mistaken: that assert would work just fine regardless of the value of mutex -- it doesn't evaluate the mutex at all, it only asserts the relationship between sizes of the different types involved.

I have another question regarding how the `sizeof()` operator is able to compute the size of member of the union without evaluating/de-referencing the mutex pointer ?

Comment: @strikersps *how the sizeof() operator is able to compute the size of member of the union without evaluating/de-referencing the mutex pointer*  Per [**6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4) (bolding mine):  "The size is determined from the **type** of the operand. ... the operand is **not evaluated** and the result is an integer constant."  The size of the *type* is fixed and known at compile time so the value `mutex` in `mutex->__size` is never used.